# Can lightning bend metal?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, magnetic-fields, lightning

If lightning strikes a metal pole, will it bend because of the force exerted by Earth's magnetic field on the current?

Answer (score 1):

The intensity of Earth's magnetic field is [25 to 65 µT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Intensity). The electric current of a typical lightning strike is about [30 kA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Return_stroke). The resulting Laplace force is around 1 Newton per meter of pole. A pole or rod wide enough to not be vaporized by the current would most likely not be bent by such a small force.

For comparison, a typical telephone pole with a diameter of 20 cm would be subjected to the same force by a wind speed of ~10 km/h (light breeze).